# A program to measure the amount of energy spent during an exercise

Tags: java

When I input 168, I get 3793, but according to the example, I'm supposed to get 2290. The problem is, the example says its calculation may be incorrect. Here's my program:

[image]

This was a lab test at my university. I submitted the .java file through [DOMJudge](https://www.domjudge.org/). I believe my program is correct, but it showed me that the program was wrong, and I failed, so here I am.

**The problem**:

To measure the amount of energy spent during an exercise use the formula: METs x 3.5 x (weight in ​kg​) / 200 = calories burned per minute​.

For example, say you weigh 160 pounds (approximately 73 kg) and you play singles tennis,
which has a MET value of 8. The formula would work as follows: 8 x 3.5 x 73 / 200 = 10.2 calories per minute. If you play
tennis for an hour, you’ll burn about 613 calories.

**Write a program that accepts an integer the weight of a person and calculates the total number
of calories the person burned while running for 45 minutes, playing tennis for 45 minutes, and sleeping for 8 hours.** Met values to use:

● Running: 10 METS
● Tennis: 8 METS
● Sleeping: 1 MET

**Rules**:

1. Your program should output a single number rounded to an integer.
2. Your output should look exactly like on the samples
   below with any number entered as a weight. Different wording, extra “spaces”, extra “lines”
   are graded by the system as a “wrong-answer"

*Here ◦ is a space and ↵ is a new line character.*

[image]

(*calculations in the example may not be correct*)

**My solution**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Energy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbdInputs = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Input person\'s weight in kg: ");
        int weight = kbdInputs.nextInt();

        double total_calories_burned = ((10*3.5*weight/200)*45) + ((8*3.5*weight/200)*45) + ((1*3.5*weight/200)*480);
        System.out.println(Math.round(total_calories_burned));
        
        kbdInputs.close();
    }

}
```

What's wrong? Thank you for taking time to read this.

Comment: Can you change the `200` integer to a `200.0` double value?

Comment: *What is wrong?*

Comment: Does your code yield the correct output for the integer weights shown (168 and 173)? Do you need to support weights entered with decimal places e.g. 100.5?

Comment: Showing us the output your program produces would be very helpful as most likely the output is correct but the formatting is just slightly wrong and your automated scoring system doesn't like it.

Comment: I changed 200 to 200.0, it's still the same

Comment: What bugs me is the example itself says its calculation may be incorrect. Then how do I test my program?

Comment: I only take integers as inputs, as the problem says.

Comment: Why does it say *(calculations in the example may not be correct)*?

Comment: Your code looks good. Try `(int)total_calories_burned` instead of rounding

Comment: @user7 I don't know either. That's stupid. The example should be accurate.

Comment: @randomdude You can always email your teacher if you think there was a problem with the judging system, can't you?

Comment: @Janez Kuhar I can, but before that i wanna be confident that my program is correct.

Comment: @user7 using (int) will just omit the numbers after decimal. The problem says to round the result.

Comment: The assignment and your interpretation of the results inconsistently mixed up lbs and kg,  (The same problem that doomed a Mars lander) I don't know if this is deliberate as a trick question, or just a badly worded assignment.  Where did 168kg and 173kg input come from?

Comment: @Jim Garrison, Yeah I noticed that too. But the problem tells me to ask for weight in kg and nothing was mentioned about converting lbs to kg. Which is why I assume it's badly worded. 168 and 173 are arbitrary numbers used for examples (at least that's what I think).

Comment: But you used the output for 160 ***lbs*** input in the assignment and compared it to the output for 168 ***kg***.  Validate your output for matching input.

Comment: That's a different example to show how to use the formula. My program should match with the last table. I tried both though, but still nothing.

Comment: Do you have an example of the correct output? The question asks about calories burned for three different types of activity, but you only show one.

Comment: @NomadMaker I added them together (that's what the question says). And the last table in the picture contains the example outputs I have.